# How do I add the interactive user to a directory in a localized Windows using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

How do I add the Swedish interactive user,

```
NT INSTANS\INTERAKTIV
```

or the English interactive user,

```
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
```

or any other localised user group with **write** permissions to a program folder's ACL?

Is this question actually "How do I use **secureObject**"? I cannot use the **LockPermissions Table** because I undestand inheritance is removed. **secureObject** permissions seem to require **CreateDirectory** rather than **Directory**...

Comment: I wonder who in hell had the idea to translate the account names to other languages! This leads to all kinds of problems where none are expected!  
Translating the screen names really would have been enough!

Comment: @Sam - Have you seen how the non-roaming appdata path is localised in Windows XP? E.g. for Notes in Swedish, 

"C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Lokala Inställningar\Application Data\Lotus\Notes\Data"... 

Which is <ENGLISH>\<ENGLISH>\<ENGLISH>\<SWEDISH>\<ENGLISH>\<ENGLISH>\etc..."

Of what possible benefit is that?

Comment: @Sam - The account names *are* the screen names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With recent releases of Wix, you can retrieve the localized names of often-used built-in user and group names via a property. For example, `WIX_ACCOUNT_NETWORKSERVICE` contains the localized name of the Network Service account. Unfortunately, as of 3.0.4513 `NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE` is not among them.

There exists a sample MSI custom action that creates properties for many of the built-in user and group names.  [Get it here](http://www.installsite.org/files/iswi/SIDLookup.zip).  Add the CA to your Wix installer and schedule it early in the install execute sequence.

Once you have the localized account name, add a PermissionEx element to modify your directory's ACL. For example:

```
<Directory ...>
   <Component ...>
      <CreateFolder>
         <PermissionEx User="[SID_INTERACTIVE]" .../>
      </CreateFolder>
   </Component ...>
</Directory ...>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no way *as such* to add both account names to an ACL since they are one and the same. The name you see corresponds to a SID, and that SID is identical in both the English and Swedish localizations. In the case of the INTERACTIVE group, that SID is `S-1-5-4`.

I haven't followed WiX in a long while, but I expect there has to be a way to specify SIDs for ACLs instead of account names. You should never, ever rely on the account name for well-known accounts unless there is absolutely no way to avoid it. Here is a [list of well-known SIDs](http://www.siao2.com/2008/06/24/8639579.aspx) for reference.

Edit: [This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/39d9e905-2b35-4ce9-a544-4564f6b5a376/) seems to provide a solution to your problem using a custom action to translate the SIDs to account names - apparently WiX doesn't out of the box support using SIDs for Permission or PermissionEx objects.

Here is a more authoritative list of well-known SIDs in [Q243330](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q243330) of the Microsoft Knownledge Base.

Comment: Thanks, I meant the interactice user in any language, so you´re right that if I can use the SID that resolves to the user then I'm past the language problem. I still need a good example in WiX of how to do just this.

Comment: Yup, using the SID is the fix. I've edited my answer to include new information. Perhaps you could also edit your question to better reflect what we've found out.